# Unlike FCI, doesn't AG make use of heartbeat to check for server down?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, sql-server-2019

SQL AG in WSFC checks whether server is down via the lease timeout

Where as SQL FCI checks whether server down via heartbeat

Does the SQL AG not make use of heartbeat at all?

Below is a sample log from AG that mentions heartbeat: [image]

Comment: Are both SQL FCI and AG same ?

Comment: Obviously not. But the logs for both show me the keyword heartbeat. So I'm trying to understand the concept whether AG has any use of heartbeat or it only relies on lease timeout.

Comment: Please put both the logs so that we can also see

Answer (score 2):

> SQL AG in WSFC checks whether server is down via the lease timeout

Not quite, that's for split brain. FCIs and AGs use the same health check method which is a combination of diagnostic data results and service status.

> Where as SQL FCI checks whether server down via heartbeat

What heartbeat? There is no heartbeat for SQL.

> Does the SQL AG not make use of heartbeat at all?

No because none exists.

Comment: I read that lease timeout in AG is related to server down. And health check timeout (call to diagnostics SP) is related to server unresponsive. Where does the heartbeat fit in here?

Comment: @variable I would urge you to read what I had written. There is no heartbeat.

Comment: I mean the cluster heartbeat. The level 1 implies either heartbeat or lease timeout failure.

Comment: The cluster connectivity heartbeat has nothing to do with SQL Server. To reiterate, there is a diagnostic result set at intervals and in an AG it has an additional lease. Both also check the service status. There is nothing else.